# A harder robot-control puzzle

Tags: pattern, visual, strategy

[image]

The goal is to find a sequence (a "program") of max 5 commands that will move the triangle (the "robot") through the grid and make it visit all the squares marked with a star.

Two types of commands can be used:

- P0 makes the sequence start over.
- The arrows (↑, ↱, ↰) move the triangle (forward) or make it change orientation (clockwise, anti-clockwise).

Each command can (but does not need to) have a color. A colored command is only executed if the triangle is in a square of the same color.

Attempting to move out of the board is not allowed.

You can play with it [here](https://gauss-turing.herokuapp.com/beta/puzzling-fec907973e9f891106640972844dd39e?goto=demo) if you want (no signup required). I'm the dev.

(Hopefully, this one won't be as easy as the one from 2 weeks ago.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following program should work:

> Forward if yellow -> Forward -> Forward -> Turn left -> Restart

Answer (score 3):

Alternative solution:

> left - run on purple - run - right on green - repeat

Comment: Oh! I thought if the bot runs out of the board, you loose.

Comment: @FlorianF Yes, but it won't because the game ends once the bot has cleared all the stars.

Comment: Sorry, it is in fact as I first though, you can fall off.  The colored instructions made it look like the bot bumps against the bottom border.  So the solution is perfect.

Comment: @FlorianF No worries.